# Wait for unityEvent to finish

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wait, unity-editor

I am trying to use UnityEvent and wanted to use them for my movement script.
Here is a part of what I have:

```
if(movementEnabled){
   BeforeMovement.Invoke();
   transform.localPosition = upcommingLocalPosition;
   OnMovement.Invoke();
}
```

My problem here is that I would need the UnityEvent "BeforeMovenent" to end before continuing to the next line, so to make sure all method in it have completed their task before moving.

In short, I am looking for something similar to a Wait() method.

Is there any way I can achieve this using UnityEvent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UnityEvents are synchronous, so as long as your event listeners aren't doing anything asynchronous you should be fine